# i am confused with the R implementation of lag in Regression analysis

Tags: r, regression, lag

look at this linear regression: Y ~ X + lag(X,1) ,the meaning is very clear that it is trying to do a linear regression. and the lag(X,1) means the first lag of X. What confuse me is the R implementation of lag function. In R the lag(X, 1) moves X to the prior time, for example

```
>library(zoo) 
>
>str(zoo(x))
‘zoo’ series from 1 to 4 
Data: num [1:4] 11 12 13 14
Index:int [1:4] 1 2 3 4
>lag(zoo(x))
1  2  3
12 13 14
```

when you regress, which value does the R use exactly at time 2? I guess R use the data like this:

```
time 1   2   3   4
 Y      anything
 X   11  12  13  14
lagX 12  13  14
```

But this is nonsense！ Because we are supposed to use the fisrt lag of X and the current X at time 2 (or any specific time ), that is 11 and 12 , not 13 12 as above! The fisrt lag of X should be the prior X , isn't it? I am so confused! Please explain to me, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question starts out with:

> look at this linear regression: Y ~ X + lag(X,1) ,the meaning is very clear 
>   that it is trying to do a linear regression. and the lag(X,1) means the first 
>   lag of X

Actually that is not the case.  It does not refer to this model:

```
Y[i] = a + b * X[i] + c * X[i-1] + error[i]
```

It actually refers to this model:

```
Y[i] = a + b * X[i] + c * X[i+1] + error[i]
```

which is not likely what you intended.

It is likely that you wanted `lag(X, -1)` rather than `lag(X, 1)`.  Lagging a series in R means that the lagged series starts earlier which implies that the series itself moves forward.

The other item to be careful of is that `lm` does not align series.  It knows nothing about the time index.  You will need to align the series yourself or use a package which does it for you.

More on these points below.

**ts**

First let us consider `lag.ts` from the core of R since `lag.zoo` and `lag.zooreg` are based on it and consistent with it.  `lag.ts` lags the times of the series so that the lagged series starts earlier.  That is if we have a series whose values are 11, 12, 13 and 14 at times 1, 2, 3 and 4 respectively `lag.ts` lags each time so that the lagged series has the same values 11, 12, 13 and 14 but at the times 0, 1, 2, 3.  The original series started at 1 but the lagged series starts at 0.  Originally the value 12 was at time 2 but in the lagged series the value 13 is at time 2.   In code, we have:

```
tt <- ts(11:14)
cbind(tt, lag(tt), lag(tt, 1), lag(tt, -1))
```

gives:

```
Time Series:
Start = 0 
End = 5 
Frequency = 1 
  tt lag(tt) lag(tt, 1) lag(tt, -1)
0 NA      11         11          NA
1 11      12         12          NA
2 12      13         13          11
3 13      14         14          12
4 14      NA         NA          13
5 NA      NA         NA          14
```

**zoo**

`lag.zoo` is consistent with `lag.ts`.  Note that since zoo represents irrelgularly spaced series it cannot assume that time 0 comes before time 1.  We could only make such an assumption if we knew the series were regularly spaced. Thus if time 1 is the earliest time in a series the value at this time is dropped since there is no way to determine what earlier time to lag it to.  The new lagged series now starts at the second time value in the original series. This is similar to the `lag.ts` example except in the lag.ts there was a 0 time and in this example there is no such time.  Similarly we cannot extend the time scale forward in time either.

```
library(zoo)
z <- zoo(11:14)
merge(z, lag(z), lag(z, 1), lag(z,-1))
```

giving:

```
   z lag(z) lag(z, 1) lag(z, -1)
1 11     12        12         NA
2 12     13        13         11
3 13     14        14         12
4 14     NA        NA         13
```

**zooreg**

The zoo package does have a zooreg class which assumes regularly spaced series except for some missing values and it can deduce what comes before just as ts can.  With zooreg it can deduce that time 0 comes before and time 5 comes after.

```
library(zoo)
zr <- zooreg(11:14)
merge(zr, lag(zr), lag(zr, 1), lag(zr,-1))
```

giving:

```
  zr lag(zr) lag(zr, 1) lag(zr, -1)
0 NA      11         11          NA
1 11      12         12          NA
2 12      13         13          11
3 13      14         14          12
4 14      NA         NA          13
5 NA      NA         NA          14
```

**lm**

`lm` does not know anything about `zoo` and will ignore the time index entirely.  If you want to not ignore it, i.e. you want to align the series involved prior to running the regression, use the dyn (or dynlm) package. Using the former:

```
library(dyn)
set.seed(123)
zr <- zooreg(rnorm(10))
y <- 1 + 2 * zr + 3 * lag(zr, -1)
dyn$lm(y ~ zr + lag(zr, -1))
```

giving:

```
Call:
lm(formula = dyn(y ~ zr + lag(zr, -1)))

Coefficients:
(Intercept)           zr  lag(zr, -1)  
          1            2            3
```

**Note 1:** Be sure to read the documentation in the help files: `?lag.ts` , `?lag.zoo` , `?lag.zooreg` and `help(package = dyn)`

**Note 2:** If the direction of the lag seems confusing you could define your own function and use that in place of `lag`.  For example, this gives the same coefficients as the lm output shown above:

```
Lag <- function(x, k = 1) lag(x, -k)
dyn$lm(y ~ zr + Lag(zr))
```

An additional word of warning is that unlike `lag.zoo` and `lag.zooreg` which are consistent with the core of R, `lag.xts` from the xts package is inconsistent.  Also the `lag` in dplyr is also inconsistent (and to make things worse if you load dplyr then dplyr will mask `lag` in R with its own inconsistent version of `lag`.  Also note that `L` in dynlm works the same as `Lag` but wisely used a different name to avoid confusion.

Comment: Thank you.There is still something unclear to me. Yves Croissant and Giovanni Millo, who write the plm package, surprisingly used lag( X, 1) in their book "Panal data Econometrics in R : the plm package" in page 9, though they had mentioned _"Note that R’s diff() and lag() functions do not compute correctly these transformations for panel data because they are unable to identify when there is a change in individual in the data. They have been therefore rewritten in order to handle correctly panel data"_ ahead. Didn't they know that they should use something esle rather than lag(X,1)?

Comment: ts, zoo, etc. work on time series data.  Panel data in wide form are multivariate time series so these classes could be used but panel data expressed in long form are not time series so these classes are not applicable.   If we have long form panel data `DF <- data.frame(id = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2), x = 1:6)` then we can create a lagged column using `transform(DF, lagx = ave(x, id, FUN = function(x) c(NA, x[-length(x)])))`

Comment: Also, note that the question was about zoo objects.  If you are dealing with plm objects (this was never mentioned in the question) then you are likely dealing with pseries objects and `lag.pseries` works in the opposite direction as `lag.ts` (and `lag.zoo` and `lag.zooreg`) so it is inconsistent with the rest of R.  In my opinion, this is a design error and they ought to have used a different name rather than `lag` to prevent confusion.

Comment: @Grok Here is what they do `R> log(emp) ~ lag(log(emp), 1) + lag(log(emp), 2) + lag(log(wage), 2) + lag(log(wage), 3) + diff(capital, 2) + diff(capital, 3)` the emp comes from EmplUK in plm, `>class(EmplUK$emp)`get`numeric`, so `emp` is not a `pseries`. The `EmplUK` is a normal data.frame, they use `plm.data` to add `index`:`R> EmplUK <- plm.data(EmplUK, index = c("firm", "year"))` the result EmplUK is still a data.frame, so `wage`and`capital`are also normal numeric, not `pseries`. what is going on?

Comment: `emp` is not a time series or a pseries -- it is a numeric vector and that vector has multiple time series in it one after another.   Thus lag.default will be used and that has the effect of converting emp to a ts object and then shifting the time index but that will not respect boundaries of the different time series which it has no idea of.

Comment: i am sorry i still don't understand. Yes, `lag(log(emp),1)`converts it into a `ts` object, but as you said before, it still take `emp` to prior time, which is wrong. We should take `emp` to later time to get the real lag, should we?

Comment: If `emp` were a numeric vector representing a single time series then `lag(emp, -1)` would be the same as `lag(ts(emp), -1)` and this would create a ts series in which the time is lagged and so the series is moved forward; however, in fact `emp` consists of 140 separate series, one for each firm. `lag` has no idea that that is the case -- all it knows is that you gave it a numeric vector and what that vector means is unknown to it thus it will lag a series into adjacent series.  Also, the various lags have different time indexes which would have to be aligned prior to using in lm as mentioned.

Comment: Also, if you have more questions on plm you probably need to start a completely new question since plm was never discussed in this question.

Comment: But i think the question about plm and the question in title is the same thing, the difference is the later one is an abstraction of the fromer. And i agree with you in that lag( emp) lags a series into adjacent series. So do you mean that whichever we use, the `lag( emp, 1)` or the `lag(emp, -1)` ,are both wrong, or that the `lag(emp, 1)` in the book is the right one and the other one is wrong? After all, Yves Croissant and Giovanni Millo used the `lag( emp, 1)`,  did they make such a big mistake?

Comment: I think the violation problem is not a big deal, after all, single wrong value won't have big impact, i guess. I think the real problem is the lag(emp, -1) or the lag( emp, 1), using lag( emp, 1) makes all wrong, and using lag( emp, -1) makes wrong value at the boundry, isn't it?

Comment: The proper way to do this with the plm package is to ensure you create a pseries vector p and then use lag(p), which will dispatch lag.pseries and properly handle the individual series; however, note that lag.pseries uses the opposite convention as the core of R so one uses lag(p) and not lag(p, -1).  This is really getting way off topic of the original question.

Answer (score 1):

Please, consult the [manual](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/lag.html) first:

> ### Description
>
> Compute a lagged version of a time series, shifting the time base back by a given number of observations.
>
> ### Default S3 method:
>
> lag(x, k = 1, ...)
>
> #### Arguments
>
> *x* A vector or matrix or univariate or multivariate time series
>
> *k* The number of lags (in units of observations).

So, `lag` does not return a lagged value. It returns the entire lagged time series, shifted back by some `k`. This is not something a simple `lm` can work with, and indeed not what you want to use. This, however, does work for me:

```
library(zoo)

x <- zoo(c(11, 12, 13, 14))
y <- c(1, 2.3, 3.8, 4.2)

lagged <- lag(x, -1)
lagged <- c(lagged, c=0) # first lag is defined as zero

model <- lm(y ~ x + lagged)
summary(model)
```

Returns:

```
Call:
lm(formula = y ~ x + lagged)

Residuals:
         1          2          3          4 
-8.327e-17 -1.833e-01  3.667e-01 -1.833e-01 

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)
(Intercept) -8.86333    4.20149  -2.110    0.282
x            0.89667    0.38456   2.332    0.258
lagged       0.05333    0.08199   0.650    0.633

Residual standard error: 0.4491 on 1 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.9687,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.9062 
F-statistic: 15.49 on 2 and 1 DF,  p-value: 0.1769
```

Comment: Thank you.There is still something unclear to me. Yves Croissant and Giovanni Millo, who write the plm package, surprisingly used lag( X, 1) in their book "Panal data Econometrics in R : the plm package" in page 9, though they mentioned _"Note that R’s diff() and lag() functions do not compute correctly these transformations for panel data because they are unable to identify when there is a change in individual in the data. They have been therefore rewritten in order to handle correctly panel data"_ ahead. Didn't they know that they should use lag(X,-1)?